# How to convert a string to an array for the columns of a DataTable?

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I have the following code that works perfectly, but I would like to replace the array of columns with a variable.
I have created in php the string:

```
$datos = "[{data: 'id'},{data: 'nombre'},{data: 'telefono'},{data: 'email'},{data: 'status'}]";
```

and in Javascript I try to associate it with the DataTable:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var result = JSON.parse('<?php echo $result ?>'); 
    var datos = '<?php echo $datos ?>'; 
    //var datos = JSON.stringify('<?php echo $datos ?>');
    //var datos = JSON.parse('<?php echo $datos ?>');   
    
    var table = $('#registros').DataTable({
        data: result,
        columns: datos
        /*columns: [{data: 'id'},{data: 'nombre'},{data: 'telefono'},{data: 'email'},{data: 'status'}]*/
    });

});
</script>
```

but that doesn't work, the conversion of the string "datos" is not done well. I have tried with:

```
var datos = JSON.stringify('<?php echo $datos ?>');
```

and with

```
var datos = JSON.parse('<?php echo $datos ?>');
```

but I don't get it. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can declare a JavaScript object literal by removing the quotes around the php part, so JavaScript sees an object and not a string.  `var datos = <?php echo $result ?>`

Comment: Perfect James, that is the solution: 
`var datos = <?php echo $datos ?>;`
thanks!

Comment: And this is also how this line is simplified:
`var result = <?php echo $result ?>;`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are doing wrong over here is, columns array look out for title paramter along with data to render column header. So can you try ahead with this

```
$datos = [
        { "data": "id", "title": "id" },
        { "data": "number", "title": "nombre" }
    ];
```

where data param is key of your result response & title is column header.

Comment: James gave me the solution: 
`var datos = <?php echo $datos ?>;`
Anyway, thanks for your response.